# coherent topology, prove normality

Tags: general-topology

I try solve a Munkres's question.

I have already solved a+b.

(There is a mistake in line 3, the right topology is that U is open in X if $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ for each i.)
[image]

for c: I've tried using the hint.

defined $Y_0 = A\cup B$, and for any $n>=0$ $Y_n=A\cup B\cup X_n$.

Then $f_0:Y_0\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $ f_0(A)={0}$ and $f_0(B)={1} $ is be continuous.

Now assume we have continuous function $f_n:Y_0\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $ f_n(A)={0}$ and $f_n(B)={1}$, then I want to build $f_{n+1}:Y_0\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that.
But this is where my problem is. I think I need  to use Tietze theorem but I'm not sure how. I after that it's not clear to me how to get continuous $F:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ that  separates A and B.

Will appreciate any help and idea.

Comment: Wouldn't you define $U$ to be open in $X$ iff $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X_i$ instead? Otherwise the definition of your topology would be circular: In that case $U$ would be open in $X$ iff $U\cap X_i$ is open in $X$ but how can you tell when that holds?

Comment: @DavidMolano This is the definition. I don't understand your queastion.

Comment: There is a typo in the definition you're using. It says that the open sets of $X$ are the ones which intersected with each $X_i$ are open in $X$. They have to be open in $X_i$ instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested Sequence of Topological Space and the Coherent Topology; Munkres Topology 35.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379923/nested-sequence-of-topological-space-and-the-coherent-topology-munkres-topology)

Comment: @DavidMolano you right. It's just a typo in the source, I used the right one while solving. Added a comment about that.
Do you have thoughts about c?

Comment: @DavidMolano yes it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the result is true even if the $(X_i)_i$ are not nested. Suppose each $X_i$ is a closed subspace of $X$. You've defined $f_0.$ So suppose we have defined $f_n:X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n\cup A\cup B\to [0,1].$ Note that $X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n\cup A\cup B\cap X_{n+1}$ is closed in $X_{n+1}$ (why?) so we can extend $f_n|_{X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n\cup A\cup B\cap X_{n+1}}$ to a function $\tilde f$ on $X_{n+1.}$ Observe that $X_{n+1}$ and $X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_n\cup A\cup B$ are closed in $X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_{n+1}\cup A\cup B$ so the gluing lemma applied to $f_n$ and $\tilde f$ provides a continuous $f_{n+1}:X_1\cup\cdots\cup X_{n+1}\cup A\cup B\to [0,1]$ and by construction $f_{n+1}$ extends $f_n.$ So the induction proceeds and we obtain a function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1.$ All that remains is to prove that $f$ is continuous, but this follows from the fact that in this topology, a map from $X$ to another topological space is continuous if and only if the restrictions to each $X_i$ are.